# Pinta Image editor for linux

Tags: 14.04, wine, executable, pinta

I have heard that you can't run exe/dll files on linux, only wine or cygwin will help to run it, I installed Pinta on my Ubuntu 14.04lts, when I went to its folder to create a launcher, I found .dll files and the main program was in .exe, I've never installed wine or anything related to it, how it is possible ? It's running perfect !

[image]
[image]

I have installed Pinta and its running fine , perfect, I never event touched wine or any other application like it, im just asking how its possible, and I know how to install wine, please read my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i got it, 2 days ago i installed mono complete , runtime environment + IDE for c# work, after reading about mono i got it, its helping ubuntu to run Pinta.exe

Answer (score 1):

If you look on the [pinta github](https://github.com/PintaProject/Pinta) it says it requires mono and that it's built with Gtk# which uses the C# language. C# requires a runtime to run (a bit like java) and on Ubuntu it is achieved by using mono which is an open-source implemntation of `.NET`. So it's perfectly normal that it's the '.exe' that's being called.

You can find more information about mono [here](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/), I'm afraid I've told you everything I can about it!

Answer (score 0):

Pinta Image Editor (*pinta*) from the default Ubuntu repositories can be installed using the following command:

```
sudo apt install pinta
```

Comment: did u read my question?

Comment: I don't have any idea how Pinta could be running fine unless it was already installed somehow or other.

Answer (score 0):

The [Pinta package for Ubuntu includes pinta.exe and *.dll files](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/all/pinta/filelist). It is [open-source software that runs on Linux, Mac, Windows, and BSD](https://pinta-project.com/pintaproject/pinta/).